# Uploadify doesn't work in localhost

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, uploadify

`uploadify` plugin is not saving images at all on `localhost`, but it doesn't report any error. what can be the problem?

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{   

    $('#file_upload').uploadify({   
        'uploader'  : 'include/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'    : 'include/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg' : 'include/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'    : 'images/profile',
        'auto'      : true,
        'multi'     : false
    });
});
</script>
```

and the call looks like this

```
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
```

Comment: i found the solution. it was problem because I was using absolute paths, and I should use relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. it was problem because I was using absolute paths, and I should use relative.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the root location eg. /srv/www/include/uploadify/uploadify.php
or whatever your directory is.

Comment: I was putting absolute addresses like this:
http://localhost/project/include/uploadify/uploadify.php
is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Target file location is a folder, so Change this line:

```
'folder'    : 'images/profile',
```

to

```
'folder'    : 'images/profile/',
```